# Update multiple rows using Prisma without manual loops

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have following prisma.schema:

```
model Tag {
  id    Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String    @unique
  files FileTag[]
}

model FileTag {
  tag    Tag  @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  tagId  Int
  file   File @relation(fields: [fileId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  fileId Int

  @@id([fileId, tagId])
}
```

Here is my code to update database:

```
for (const tagId of tagIds){
    const tag = await Tags.addFileToTag(parseInt(tagId), fileId);
};

async addFileToTag(tagId: number, fileId: number) {
    const client = await getDbClient();

    return await client.tag.update({
      where: {
        id: tagId,
      },

      data: {
        files: {
          create: {
            fileId
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

My goal is reached by this implementation. But the problem is, I don't like this implementation. I am using a loop and calling same **update** query repeatedly.

Now, I am wondering is there any alternative procedure, (i.e change prisma **update** to **updateMany** query) by removing the loop... that will do the same change on database?

Answer (score 11):

`updateMany` is used to update the same data in many rows but in your case, you want to update different data, so `updateMany` won't be useful here.

Optionally you could use [transactions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api) if atomicity is required and there is a need to make sure that either all tags are updated or if there is any error then no tags gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Prisma in a NestJs project, and I'm leaving my solution here that may be helpful to someone someday.

I had something like that:

```
model Job {
  id                  Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  authorId            Int
  position            String
  type                String
  description         String
  requirement         String
  requirementItems    RequirementItem[] 
  task                String
  location            String
  company             String
  companyWebsite      String  
  createdAt           DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt           DateTime @updatedAt
  author              User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  application         Application[]

}

model RequirementItem {
  jobId     Int
  item      String
  job       Job     @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I had to update the Job model and also the RequirementItem with new values coming from the frontend.

I'm not sure my solution is the best one, but I deleted all the items in  RequirementItem with the same jobId and created them with new values in the same query as below:

```
async editJob(jobId: number, job: CreateJobDto, userId: number) {
    const publishedJob = await this.prisma.job.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: jobId,
      },
    });

    if (!publishedJob) {
      throw new NotFoundException('There is no job with this id');
    }

    if (publishedJob.authorId !== userId) {
      throw new ForbiddenException(
        "You cannot edit a job that you didn't published",
      );
    }

    const { requirementItems, taskItems } = job;

    return await this.prisma.job.update({
      where: { id: jobId },
      data: {
        ...job,
        requirementItems: {
          // deleted all records
          deleteMany: {
            jobId: jobId,
          },
          // created new records
          create: requirementItems,
        },
      },
    });
  }
```