# Access each record (or this) when using Prisma updateMany

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

How can I access each element that is affected by Prisma's updateMany method?

I would like to update the values based on the current value of each record:

```
   // I want to achieve something like that
   prisma.user.updateMany((record) => {

      // access the current record
      const recordID = record.id 

      // return or update the record
      return { data: { encryptedId: encrypt(recordID) }};
       };
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509069/7767387) you may use `$transaction` with `map`

```
// recordIDs array of ids
await prisma.$transaction(
  recordIDs.map((recordID) =>
    prisma.user.update({
      where: { id: recordID },
      data: { encryptedId: encrypt(recordID) },
    }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Ok, so I have to perform 2 queries to achieve this?
 1. query all user (and extract the recordIDs)
 2. use that array to perform update actions.

Is this good from a performance perspective?

Comment: If you use raw sql, how can I update multiple rows with different values based in the row itself in one query?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this implementation:

```
 await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      const ids = await tx.user.findMany({ select: { id: true } });

      await Promise.all(
        ids.map(({ id }) =>
          tx.user.update({ where: { id }, data: { recordId: id } })
        )
      );
```

Comment: Use interactive transactions with caution. Keeping transactions open for a long time hurts database performance and can even cause deadlocks. Try to avoid performing network requests and executing slow queries inside your transaction functions. We recommend you get in and out as quick as possible! [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#interactive-transactions)